# Digitally Signing Vbscript with timestamp

Tags: vbscript, digital-signature

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" &_ 
"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objSigner=CreateObject("Scripting.Signer")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("F:\\Code\\signedscripts")
Set colListOfFiles = objFolder.Files
Cert = "Example"
Store = "ROOT"
For each objFile in colListOfFiles
objSigner.SignFile objFile, Cert, Store
Next
```

I am using the above script to digitally sign vbscripts and now I need to timestamp the signed scripts. How to use timestamp in this script ?

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamp the scripts". Please provide an example of the desired result.

Comment: I meant, when you digitally sign a executable, you can include time and date when the executable was signed as a part of certificate.